# How Do I check In which place our localStrorage data stored in our system?

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented the login functionality in which i have to set the uname and password into the `localStorage` API.I want to know which place our data will be stored?

```
localStorage.setItem('userName', JSON.stringify(data.uname));
localStorage.getItem('userName');
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, just go to the developer tools by pressing F12, then go to the Application tab and then go to the Local Storage option. After that, you'll see all your local storage of browser there.

Source : [StackOverflow](//stackoverflow.com/a/12799050/4758494)

Comment: Thank you sir for this userful inforamtion.i will show the key in the localstorage but the passowrd is not show in localstrorage.?

Comment: Use this to store password `localStorage.setItem('password', JSON.stringify(data.password));`

Comment: thank you sir finally show both key in the localStorage.

Comment: Glad to help you. :)